# Where handle parameter value from wp_enqueue_style come from?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Relative to the `wp_enqueue_style()` In [documentation says](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/):

> (string) (Required) Name of the stylesheet. Should be unique.

But this is not clear to me if is a value you need to give to set a unique reference in the moment to enqueue the styles or you need to pick it up from the file name or directory.

Where this value come from?

To me is not clear in documentation.  I've read some tutorials about it, but still is not clear to me.

Comment: Well it's just totally a made up name, just in case you need to reference to it later. So to answer your main question: No you don't have to choose a name from file name or directory. However, following industry standards for naming conventions and/or using your development strategies for implementing naming conventions would be considered best practices!

Answer (score 2):

You should give a unique name for your script, e.g:

`wp_enqueue_style('myCustomStylesheet12345', 'path_to_stylesheet/stylesheet.css);`

For example:
If you later try to enqueue something with the same given handle, it wont be added. (you have to add unique name for both, or remove previous if already enqueued before enqueue the second one.)

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't clear to me. So is like an ID you give as a reference to enqueue the stylesheet in order to be unique.